# Streaming webcam data in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a Raspberry Pi (2B, running Raspbian Jessie 02/09), and a webcam (ID 041e:406c Creative Technology, Ltd Live! Cam Sync [VF0520], V4L compatible).

I'm trying to build a robot, and how I imagined the camera would work was like this:

Pi (Node.js) -> Server (Computer, Node.js, running Electron to create windows for the camera image).

The goal was to send the data from the Pi to the server using sockets (socket.io) at an useable framerate (10~20?).

I've looked into modules such as:

- node-camera, which did not work (blank image), and used websockets.
- node-opencv (opencv on npm), which failed to compile, and when it did, did not properly detect the camera (however python detected it perfectly with opencv)

A lot of the guides I've found on the internet required the client to be connected to a browser, to be able to retrieve the webcam data, which isn't what I wanted.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:**
To clarify, I have a Node.js socket.io server which I want jpeg (or other formats) webcam data to be passed to at a reasonable framerate from a Node.js (v5.6.0) client.

Comment: What _is_ what you wanted? Did you want to be able to access the webcam data via your phone? A Java app? Your question is a little open-ended. Try to be more specific.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to clarify a bit more, thank you.

Comment: Regarding the guides that require the client to be connected to a browser: you should go off of these guides, then replace the browser further down the line. In other words, figure out how to get the camera to work with node + a browser, _then_ figure out how to get the camera to work with node without a browser.

Comment: My Raspberry Pi is configured to have GUIs disabled, so I'm unsure how I would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building a robot, you should take a look at ROS (Robot Operating System). There are ROS-ready drivers for many cameras, and it has a javascript interface.

You probably want to send the data for processing of some kind. Again, if this is a robot, you should keep a proper structure of your code. Low level controllers on one part, high level controllers in another, external libraries for things like image processing in another code. With the publisher/subscriber methodology that ROS uses (also LCM which many people prefer and I find pretty cool indeed) let's you keep more order because you can share that data more easily.

Also, how the data is sent is transparent to the user. Maybe not in the most efficient way (maybe LCM has -or had, I don't know- more performance), but is very easy to implement. I would highly recommend taking a look.

Maybe this link can give an idea of what you can do: http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages

Note that socket.io claims is real time. Real time in web development means something completely different in robotics. You should keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to install `opencv` with Node.js and confirmed that it works. Here's how I did it:

- Install and compile OpenCV (3.0.0 works for what I'm using it for)
- `git clone` node-opencv
- Remove `.git` folder
- Run `npm install` in the `node-opencv` folder
- Rename `node-opencv` to `opencv` and move to `node_modules`
- `cd` to project dir (the directory containing the `node_modules` that contains `opencv`)

I got these instructions from a response to an issue posted in `node-opencv`'s github issue tracker.

If the camera fails to open after installing, it is because the user does not have access to `/dev/video`. This is something I realized after I spent hours trying to figure out why I couldn't open the camera.

In most distributions, you just have to add yourself to the `video` group to be able to access all `/dev/video*` devices.

Comment: I have been able to run electron after following these steps. However, I can't get the video to come up. I access my PI using VNC but that shouldnt  cause problem on the video. I checked that 'pi' user is in the 'video' group. Any ideas?